# Server Sent Events EventSource is not called continually in firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, firefox, server-sent-events

I'm working on Server sent Events (Html5) in asp.net project. The code is so simple as it receives data from the server and show it inside a DIV.
The problem is only appear when I run the code on FireFox where Eventsource is not called all the time, Firebug shows 2 requests or 12 requests or sometimes only 1 request.
when i test the code on chrome, the code works fine and i got infinite requests as i need.
my Code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
if (window.EventSource == undefined)
    {
        $('#targetDiv').html('Your Browser Cant support Server Side Event');
        return;
    }
var source = new EventSource('GetData.aspx?userid=jalal');

    source.onopen = function(event){$('#targetDiv').append("Connection opened... <br/>");};
    source.onerror = function(event)
    {
        if (event.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED)
            $('#targetDiv').append("Connection Closed!<br/>");

        source.addEventListener("new-message", function (event) {});
    };
    source.onmessage = function(event){$('#targetDiv').append(event.data + '<br/>')};
});
</script>

<div id="targetDiv">

</div>
```

and the Code behind for the page GetData.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now;
    Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
    Response.Expires = -1;
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";

    Response.Write("data: " + Request.QueryString["userid"] + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n\n ");
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Can Anyone give me an idea of what is wrong in the above code or why this happened only in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution for the php server side , which is we need to give some sleep to server  at least by 1 second.

```
Response.Flush();
sleep(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make proper use of EventSource, your server-side code needs to continuously write to the `Response`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now;
    Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
    do {
        Response.Write("data: " + Request.QueryString["userid"] + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n\n ");
        Response.Flush();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    } while (true);
}
```